# Непонятное поведение компилятора (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, avr-gcc, avr

Компилятор GCC для AVR.
Поясните, пожалуйста, следующее:
в `main()` такие строчки:

```
    txPack[3] = ucPacketCounter;
    ucPacketCounter++;
```

`unsigned char ucPacketCounter` -  объявлена глобально.

После чего вывожу содержимое `txPack`, и обнаруживаю, что `txPack[3]=0` всегда.

Смотрим листинг -

```
 386:   80 91 60 00     lds r24, 0x0060
 38a:   80 93 f6 00     sts 0x00F6, r24

 38e:   8f 5f           subi    r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 390:   80 93 60 00     sts 0x0060, r24
```

Первые две строчки вполне понятны. А вот вторые?? Что за??? Туплю уже час

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница в использовании `subi` и `inc` на `avr` заключается в том, что `subi` как операция является в некотором смысле *"надмножеством"* `inc` с точно такой же стоимостью (в плане размера инструкции и времени выполнения).

`subi` может использоваться для добавления / вычитания `8bit` константы из любого `8bit` числа, а `inc`, очевидно, *используется только по прямому назначению.*

Из более общей и более конкретной инструкций с одинаковыми стоимостями компилятор выбрал первую, что, естественно, достаточно разумно.

---

Стоит также отметить, что `inc` выставляет флаги `V,N,S,Z`, в то время как `subi` - `H,V,N,S,Z,C`.

Таким образом, использование `subi` может быть также обусловлено тем, что не придется вручную или каким-либо другим способом устанавливать [**Carry flag**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Осознал, что в этом случае происходит переполнение (как бы в обратную сторону, не знаю как правильно назвать), и результат идентичен инкременту.
Но есть же команда INC, реализующая аппаратный инкремент. Почему она не используется не понятно.

Comment: Насколько я понял, важен он для переменных размером больше одного регистра? Все таки раскажите!))

Comment: @decodder Ответил ответом)